# How to get postgresql database out of deadlock after django manage.py migrate script failed

Tags: django, database, postgresql, deadlock

I recently tried to run a `django manage.py migrate` command on a remote database. I believe that the connection to the database may have been interrupted during the command.

I got back this error when the command finished:

> DETAIL:  Process 11463 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 96771
>   of database 16389; blocked by process 11681. Process 11681 waits for
>   AccessShareLock on relation 25332 of database 16389; blocked by
>   process 11463.

I get the same error if I try to run the migrate command again.

What should I do to get out of this state? Should I find and kill these two blocking processes? Remove the locks?

I'm not sure what to do here and don't want to try random things that may make the situation worse. I have daily backups of this database, but would rather not lose data.

Django version 1.8.xx, PostgreSQL 9.4.15

Comment: Which migration files that you want to migrate? Is it the initial migrate?

Comment: @seuling no it’s not the initial migration. It is adding a few fields to an existing model.

Comment: Then I think it can be kind of transaction problem... can you upload your adding fields?